# Adding more fields to the add user page on dashboard

Tags: users, user-registration

I'm working on a `Wordpress` site and would like to add a few extra fields to the dashboard `user-new.php` screen so the admin can easily add new users to the site.

The fields would need to take in text data in relation to the users Address and a membership number.

Currently I've managed to get extra fields displaying on the `user-edit.php` screen. below is the code:

```
function modify_contact_methods($profile_fields){
    //Add New Fields
    $profile_fields['name'] = 'Name';
    $profile_fields['address_1'] = 'Address 1';
    $profile_fields['address_2'] = 'Address 2';
    $profile_fields['address_3'] = 'Address 3';
    $profile_fields['address_4'] = 'Address 4';
    $profile_fields['address_5'] = 'Address 5';
    $profile_fields['address_6'] = 'Address 6';

    return $profile_fields;
}

add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'modify_contact_methods');
```

Is there anyway I can do this to the add user form on dashboard? It's only the backend I'm concerned about as currently users do not register automatically for the sites services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Advanced Custom Field Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).
Very powerfull tool that let's you add custom fields anywhere and use them in the way you wish.

Comment: I actually have this plugin already, I did not know it was able to do that for the add user screen. Will try it now